# Remove index.php in Wordpress subfolders when using virtual hosts

Tags: wordpress, virtualhost, redhat

I have looked everywhere to find a solution to this problem, but nothing i have tried has worked. When having the permalink settings to /index.php/%postname%/ it works fine, but when i remove the index.php part i only get a 404 and this in the log:

```
[Tue Aug 13 05:05:46 2013] [error] [client 202.58.198.84] File does not exist: /var/www/html/domain1/postname, referer:.....
```

I have a Red Hat webserver running Apache with two Wordpress sites through with virtual hosts. The virtual hosts look like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # General
  ServerAdmin info@domain1.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain1
  ServerName domain1.com
  ServerAlias www.domain1.com

  # Logging
  ErrorLog logs/domain1-error_log
  CustomLog logs/domain1-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  # General
  ServerAdmin info@domain2.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain2
  ServerName domain2.com
  ServerAlias www.domain2.com

  # Logging
  ErrorLog logs/domain2-error_log
  CustomLog logs/domain2-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

The .htaccess file in the sub folders looks like this after changing the permalink in frontend settings.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I also tried to change

```
RewriteBase /
```

to

```
RewriteBase /subfolder
```

without any luck.

This is not a huge problem but it bugs me a lot! I would appreciate if someone had a solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that:

- your wordpress permalink settings is set to /%postname%
- the .htaccess file is placed inside /var/www/html/domain1 (same for domain2)
- you specify some rules for the domain1/2 directory like this (add this piece of code right before the `</virtualhost>` tag inside your configuration file):

  ```
  <Directory /var/www/html/domain1>
          Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
          AllowOverride All
          Order allow,deny
          allow from all
  </Directory>
  ```